# Education planning and documentation/tracking

Tags: linux, project-management, scheduling

I am training kids on electronics and microcontroller programming. For that we have dozens of practical tasks like soldering and also dozens of theoretical stuff like presentations. In addition we have some giveaways so that they can start with electronics at home.

Now, one problem comes with dependencies: for some practical tasks, you should have some theoretical information first. Later theoretical information depends on earlier theoretical information. Same for the giveaways: you should receive some of them in a particular order or it will not make sense, e.g. it's not a good idea to give them LEDs without giving them resistors first. They need the resistor to keep the LED intact.

What I need is

- a self-hosted webservice, ideally based on the LAMP stack (we already have that)
- which can model all the course content
- and allows defining the dependencies

and then

- create users
- for which I can add a checkmark if they have completed a theoretical or practical task or received an item

so that

- the trainers can see what has already been worked on
- the website can suggest which next task or topic to work on

The suggestions must depend on the kids who are actually present, i.e. I need to be able to quickly define the participants.

Example:

Week 1: Alfred, Berta, Charlie and Daniel participate in the first training. They learn the theory of resistors and start soldering. They all get some resistors.
Week 2: Alfred, Berta and Charlie participate in the second training. Daniel is ill. They learn about LEDs and still do some soldering. They all get LEDs.
Week 3: Alfred and Daniel are present. Therefore we can now repeat the LED theory for Daniel and also repeat soldering. It's not bad that Alfred got both of that information and task twice, since we need to repeat anyway. Daniel will get LEDs, but Alfred will not get LEDs again (since that's a cost factor for our charity).

Ideally the software allows having "free" tasks which a kid or student can take whenever they feel about learning more and having spare time. So, they log into the system themselves and pick a task themselves. However, these will be strictly separated, e.g. they can't pick a soldering task or high voltage task, which needs supervision.

Which software would allow such a planning and tracking?

Comment: I am not certain, but take a look at one of the LMS like Canvas (https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms), Moodle, etc.

Comment: @ZZ: that's an interesting project, but unfortunately not what I'm looking for. Thanks for pointing me to the term LMS. I'll use that for finding other projects now.